# subroutines and variable in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, console-application

I am writing a code in visual basic and I want to call a different subroutine that has specific codes regarding specific variables.

```
Dim MonthSales As Double
Call GetMonthSales()
```

In my alternate subroutine:

```
Console.WriteLine("How much did you sell this month?")
MonthSales = CDbl(Console.ReadLine())
```

What I am trying to do is get my alternate subroutine to set what I dimensioned in my main routine to whatever the user puts as their monthly sales

Comment: If you're using the Console class, you're using VB.Net rather than VBA or vbscript. And if you're using VB.Net, you should **not** use the `Call` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is poor design. Instead, write the method to return a value, like this:

```
Public Shared Function GetMonthSales() As Decimal
   Console.WriteLine("How much did you sell this month?")
   Return CDec(Console.ReadLine())
End Function
```

And then in your Main() method:

```
Dim MonthSales As Decimal = GetMonthSales()
```

It's also worth noting that you should use the `Decimal` type, not `Double`,  whenever you are working with money.

Comment: I would also suggest checking that the text the user enters is valid before converting it to a number. For example with `Decimal.TryParse`